# child and parent table errors

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables that one table is parent and the other is child.
First,in form load, I wanna add a row to Parent, after that use Parent ID in child Table.
Of course all of those are temporary, till user confirm and save finally.
But through my code, I received this error:

> ForeignKeyConstraint
>   FK_Table385_ParentTable_Table380_ChildTable
>   requires the child key values (3) to
>   exist in the parent table.

I know what this error means, and I can update Parent Table after that add rows to my child Table. But I can not do that. because all of those works are temporary till user confirm operation.
So what can I do?

Comment: What data access technology are you using? L2SQL, Entity Framework, DataSets and DataAdapters, or good old plain ADO.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configure your Typed datasets correctly this is handled automatically.

I don't recall all details but it requires the use of AutoIncrement on the PK and Cascading updates in the Relation.

You ought to see (debugger) that the new records get temporary negative values.

So if that `(3)` is the key value, something ain't right.

Comment: yes, I think you'r right. I checked Parent table and error was in that. it was not auto increment. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use Datasets: insert data offline in your application and commit to database when user confirms.

Comment: infact, I use typed dateset. both of Tables are in BindingSource form.

Comment: Did you commit master dataset first and dependent dataset last?

Comment: yes, First I added rows to Parent binding Source, then used ParentTableBindingSource.EndEdit().after that ChildTable.NewRow()

Comment: my code:  this.ParentTableBindingSource.AddNew();
            Comment.Text = _Desc;
         ...
          this.ParentTableBindingSource.EndEdit();
            for (int i = 0; i < GoodTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow Row = dataSet000.ChildTable.NewRow();
                Row["Column01"] = x;
                Row["Column02"] = y;
              ...
                dataSet000.ChildTable.Rows.Add(Row);
            }

Comment: I think the error points to a Dataset constraint, not an SQL error.